# Python 3.6.3 Idle is killing current session

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ubuntu, python-idle

I got a strange issue, where the python 3.6.3 idle is killing my current ubuntu session.
I am using ubuntu 17.10

The error only appears once per start of the linux machine and every time the idle is going to kill the idle looks like the following:

[image: idle when it is going to kill my current session]

I really hope, that anybody knows how to fix this issue.

Thank you very much

EDIT:
IDLE when I am starting my system and when it is going to kill my session
[image: Python when I am starting my system and when it is going to kill my session]

And here a picture of what it looks like, after my session got killed. IDLE seems like its still running[image]

Comment: stop using IDLE, find other python shell, editor or IDE ;)

Comment: any suggestions? :D

Comment: What exactly is happening?

Comment: On Linux Mint 18 (based on Ubuntu 16.04) I use [DreamPie](http://www.dreampie.org/) as Python Shell, [Geany](https://www.geany.org/) as editor to write and run short code and [Spyder](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/) (Installed with Anaconda) to create project with more files.

Comment: So you are stating that you can start Ubuntu, login, and wait for some random amount of time, but once you start idle in a terminal window, your system locks and requires you to login?  Does this happen when you start a terminal without starting idle?  What happens after you login again?  Is Idle still running, or do you need to restart it?  Have you looked at the system message log after this happens (journalctl | tail)?

Comment: @Greg Mueller Thanks for the reply, I added a few pictures to show how it looks like after the session got killed once

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I added a few more pictures. After starting the System and the idle, the menu of the idle looks weird and my current session is killed after a couple of seconds. The system is brining me back to the login screen. If I am logging in and starting the idle again, no errors appear and i can use it normally.

Comment: I have never used Linux, but a relative has used IDLE on an older version of Ubuntu for over a year without incident.  IDLE is a python-only program that makes little use of the os module but heavy use of tkinter, which uses tcl/tk.  So the problem is almost certainly in either the new python or tcl/tk binaries.  Have you run the python test suite?  `python3 -m test -ugui`  # perhaps add `-jn`, n = number of cores

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Hello, I executed several scripts with your parameters: "python3 -m test -ugui" and the scripts executed successfully, except an error while finding module: "/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for '02.py' (AttributeError: module '02' has no attribute '__path__')". The IDLE itself wasnt working, because of the failure I described above.

Comment: I intended for you to run the command as is, to run the entire test suite.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy hello, I did so but it is telling me the following:
/usr/bin/python3: No module named test.__main__; 'test' is a package and cannot be directly executed

Comment: If /test is present, there should be, in 3.6.3, test.__main__ containing `from test.libregrtest import main\nmain()`.  I wonder if your installation is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe IDLE is too much for your PC? Consider another IDE.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply, but I dont think that IDLE is to much for the pc :D but the error appered first time, when I was updating from 17.04 to 17.10. Reinstalling python IDLE dosnt work.

Comment: @RiftOut Then it's probably a problem of the OS, nothing you can do anything about. You can report this issue and wait for an update. If have have too much time, you could got through all update notes of ubuntu 17.04-10 and the implement a fix yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

I like to use PyCharm, which is a great python IDE, but if you want to continue using IDLE you'll have to give us more information and copy and paste the error.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your comment. 
It isnt calling an error, the IDLE menu is just looking weird after logging into ubuntu and after a couple of seconds it is killing the session and taking me back to the login screen.
But I will take a look at PyCharme meanwhile

Comment: @Rift No problem. Also, that sounds like a botched installment. Maybe try reinstalling python? PyCharm already comes with python, but if you want to stick with IDLE you may have to reinstall it.